# How to plot hyper-parameters from loop in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this kernel with the following code in which I want to run different n_estimators on my test set:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for n_estimators in [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]:
    my_mae = get_mae(n_estimators, train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y)
    print(n_estimators, my_mae)
```

The output is (n_estimators, my_mae):

- 5, 108070.017
- 25, 54273.79
- 50, 55912.80

Now, I want to plot each of these 3 data points in a chart with matplotlib. How do I do this given the code snippet below? I am not sure where in the loop to add which piece of the code for it to show. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways among others to do it:

**Plotting individual points inside the for loop**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for n_estimators in [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]:
    my_mae = get_mae(n_estimators, train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y)
    print(n_estimators, my_mae)
    plt.scatter(n_estimators, my_mae) # Way 1
    # plt.plot(n_estimators, my_mae, 'o') # Way 2
```

**Plotting all points outside the for loop**

```
my_maes = []
for n_estimators in [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]:
    my_mae = get_mae(n_estimators, train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y)
    print(n_estimators, my_mae)
    my_maes.append(my_mae)

plt.plot(n_estimators, my_mae, 'o') # Way 3
# plt.scatter(n_estimators, my_mae) # Way 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly, you want a bar chart where each tick in the horizontal axis is the number of estimators and the vertical axis represents the MAE.  Just use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) for that.  You'll also need to modify the x-axis labels so that they are custom because using the number of estimators as is will make the appearance of each bar non-uniform.  Therefore, the x-axis should be linear, say 1 through 6 with 6 being the total number of estimators you have given your example code snippet in your question, then plotting with those values and changing the x-axis labels to be the actual number of estimators instead.  You'll need [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) for changing the x-axis labels.

Therefore:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500] # New - save for plotting for later
dummy = list(range(len(values))) # Dummy x-axis values for the bar chart
maes = [] # Save the MAEs for each iteration
for n_estimators in values:
    my_mae = get_mae(n_estimators, train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y)
    maes.append(my_mae) # Save MAE for later

plt.bar(dummy, maes) # Plot the bar chart with each bar having the same distance between each other
plt.xticks(dummy, values) # Now change the x-axis labels

# Add x-label, y-label and title to the graph
plt.xlabel("Number of estimators")
plt.ylabel("MAE")
plt.title("MAE vs. Number of Estimators")
plt.show()
```